# Перенести значения с одной таблицы sql в другую с добавлением одинакового текста к одному из значений

Tags: sql

Необходимо перенести значения с одной таблицы базы данных SQL в другую. Необходимые значения для переноса это product_id (int) и product_alias (varchar).

Результирующая таблица oc_url_alias с полями:

```
url_alias_id - автоинкремент;
query - varchar;
keyword -varchar;
```

Сам запрос:

```
INSERT INTO oc_url_alias(query, keyword)
SELECT product_id, product_alias
FROM products
```

Нужно перед вставкой значения product_id в query добавить "product_id=", вот это не понимаю как сделать.

Comment: В зависимости от версии sql воспользоваться конкатенацией строк. Например для mysql `concat('product_id=', product_id)`

Comment: Отлично, спасибо большое!